# Swift osx external app dependency

Tags: macos, wireshark, tshark

im making an osx application that uses tshark (part of wireshark) in order to work. My question is how do i "inject" tshark into my application so that it doesn't become a dependency for the end user?

Comment: Why inject it? compiling it in would be the better solution.

Comment: I said injection because i thought it was the only possible solution. Can you give me any guidelines on how to compile it in order to run it in my app?